# How to add an element without changing the height of the card or disturbing position of other elements

Tags: html, css, django

How do I add an element(image) at the end without changing the height of the card, with card height set to auto

is there any way to solve this? any help is appreciated, Thanks!

```css
.card {
  width: 540px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
}

.field2 {
  font-family: inherit;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}

.log_in_instead {
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.create {
  padding-right: 70px;
}

#img101 {
  position: relative;
  left: 490px;
  top: -150px;

}
```

```html
  <div class="card">
  
    <div class="field2">
    <span class="log_in_instead"> <a href="#">Log in instead</a> </span>
    <span class="create"><button id="create_button" type="submit">Create</button></span>
    </div>
    
    <span><img src="{% static 'main/images/img101.svg' %}" id="img101"></span>

  </div>
```

This is what it should look like:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkPg2.png

This is what it looks like:        [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1ROu.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give the card position: relative and the image position: absolute. And remove the span around the image. I think it will be easier to position this way. So you can give it a bottom: -50px, right: -50px (depending on the size of your image).

And check your /button, you are not closing it.

Your code should look like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="card">

    <div class="field2">
          <span class="log_in_instead"> <a href="#">Log in instead</a</span>
          <span class="create"><button id="create_button" type="submit">Create</button></span>
    </div>

    <img src="{% static 'main/images/img101.svg' %}" id="img101"></>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 540px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
}

.field2 {
  font-family: inherit;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}

.log_in_instead {
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.create {
  padding-right: 70px;
}

#img101 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px; /*use your custom size*/
  height: 100px; /*use your custom size*/
  background-color: #000; /*only for visualization*/
  right: -50px; /*use your custom size*/
  bottom: -50px; /*use your custom size*/
}
```

Check it in codepen: https://codepen.io/flpfar/pen/vYNJGNr

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'm so sorry but that doesn't answer my question.